# How to change the default log file location in CnosDB?

Tags: database, cnosdb

There are options we can set the log level, query enabling, log format per [this doc](https://cnosdb.github.io/docs/content/cnosdb/latest/managerment/configuration.html). But is there a way I could change the default log file location in CnosDB?

Answer (score 0):

you can set the log file location in the config file, for example:
[image: for example]:

You can set all config of log in the config file, too.

Comment: can I rotate the logs?